# How to center the label vertically in relation to the neighbouring dropdown?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs in one line. The first contains a label, but is not in the centre and it looks kind of out of place compared to the neighbouring dropdown:

```
<div id="deal_modal_body" class="modal-body">
   <div class="cb_inline_block">
      <div class="cb_inline_block"> Test: </div>
      <div class="cb_inline_block">
         <div class="input-append">
            <select id="id_">
               <option selected="selected" value="">---------</option>
            </select>
            <button id="add_button" class="btn" type="button"><icon class="icon-white">Go</icon></button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a fiddle here to simply it:

http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/6EQJw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of hard-coding values to nudge stuff into the middle/center.  A better way to go would be to use **Twitter Bootstrap's** own built-in solution.

Presumably this goes inside a form right?  Just give that form a class of `form-inline`. Done.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6EQJw/5/

Reference: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms